# How to XOR hexadecimal in SML?

Tags: sml

I would like to implement a XOR(exclusive or) function into SML that is able to XOR hexadecimals.
Do I need to calculate the binary of the HEX and XOR then? And if yes, how do I do this/how do I reverse this so I get HEX as result?
An example :

xorhex (0wx4A, 0wx6F)

> val it = 0wx25 : word8

How can I implement this in preferably MoscowML?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Word`](http://sml-family.org/Basis/word.html) library has xor.

```
- Word.xorb(0wxAAAA, 0wxAAA0);
val it = 0wxA : word
```

Comment: Links to where this library is available and its documentation would be helpful.